# Iterative tree parsing in Rust

Tags: recursion, rust, iteration, borrow-checker

Suppose we have a tree:

```rust
#[derive(Default, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Tree {
    children: Vec<Tree>,
}
```

And we want to build it from a list of `bool`s where `true` is like an open tag and `false` is like a close tag in XML. I.e. `[true, true, false, true, false, false]` is

```
root -> node -> node
            `-> node
```

We can easily parse this recursively like this:

```rust
fn read_tree_recursive<'a>(tags: &mut impl Iterator<Item=&'a bool>) -> Tree {
    let mut tree = Tree::default();
    while let Some(&tag) = tags.next() {
        if tag {
            tree.children.push(read_tree_recursive(tags));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    tree
}
```

Here is some test code:

```rust
fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        read_tree_recursive(&mut [true, true, false, true, false, false].iter()),
        Tree {
            children: vec![
                Tree {
                    children: vec![
                        Tree::default(),
                        Tree::default(),
                    ],
                }
            ],
        },
    );
}
```

But how do you do this iteratively? In any other language you'd make a stack of pointers on the heap something like this:

```rust
fn read_tree_iterative(tags: &[bool]) -> Tree {
    let mut root = Tree::default();
    let tree_stack: Vec<&mut Tree> = vec![&mut root];

    for &tag in tags {
        if tag {
            tree_stack.last().unwrap().children.push(Tree::default());
            tree_stack.push(tree_stack.last().unwrap().children.last_mut().unwrap());
        } else {
            tree_stack.pop();
        }
    }
    root
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in Rust because Rust can't know that we're only ever mutating `tree_stack.last()`. The recursive version uses function calls to enforce that, but obviously it has the downsides that come with recursion.

Is there a good way around this other than resorting to `RefCell`? Unfortunately Rust doesn't have `become` so TCO isn't a good option either.

Comment: Maybe the best way is to do it recursively? What's your problem with this approach?

Comment: Stack overflows.

Comment: If that is the problem, you can use something like [stacker](https://docs.rs/stacker). This is not the best solution, as under some conditions it may allocate and deallocate a lot of stacks, but I'm afraid this is the best you can get.

Comment: If you see that there are lot of allocations and deallocations, you can also run the first invocation within [`grow()`](https://docs.rs/stacker/latest/stacker/fn.grow.html) of a big stack (or alternatively, run it on a new thread with a big stack size).

Comment: Ah that is neat; I had not heard of `stacker`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply store owned values in your stack and add them to the children when you pop them from the stack:

```
fn read_tree_iterative<'a> (tags: &mut impl Iterator<Item=&'a bool>) -> Tree {
    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    let mut last = Tree::default();
    
    for &tag in tags {
        if tag {
            stack.push (last);
            last = Tree::default();
        } else {
            let mut parent = stack.pop().unwrap();
            parent.children.push (last);
            last = parent;
        }
    }
    last
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=dbf307a10c80631ec3b61744fd335f2a)

Comment: Oh yeah. I feel stupid!